# Выборка данных с древовидной структурой

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос вида :

```
$result_msg = "SELECT id, parent_id, id_user, fromUser, text, date FROM comments WHERE fromUser = ".$from." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 20";               
$row_myM = mysql_query ($result_msg);
```

Он выбирает комментарии начиная с `$start` в кол-ве 20шт. Какие-то комментарии являются ответами на другие комментарии (с помощью поля "`parent_id`"). Как сделать так, что бы при выборке, `LIMIT` учитывался только для родительских комм-иев. Например, выбираются 20 комментариев с `parent_id = 0` (родительские) и хоть сто (т.е. все) ответов на эти комм-ии, если таковые имеются. Рекурсивная функция не нужна.

P.S. Глубина вложенности 1. Можно ответить только на родительский коммент (вдруг это упростит задачу)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, я лично считаю, что **очень и очень** не правильно то, что вы храните и комментарии, и ответы на них в одной таблице. Не уверен, что получится что-то толковое, но попробуйте так (поля допишите сами):

```
SELECT
    t1.`id` AS  child_id,
    t1.`id_user` AS  child_uid,
    t2.`id` AS parent_id,
    t2.`id_user` AS parent_uid
FROM `comments` t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        tt2.*
    FROM 
       `comments` tt2
    LIMIT 0 , 20
) t2 ON t1.`parent_id` = t2.`id`
```

И давайте псевдонимы, чтоб хоть как-то различать поля. Так же, для древовидной структуры, можно использовать рекурсивную функцию. Начинаем с нулевого уровня, вытаскиваем родителя, и передаем в эту же функцию его id, по которому вытаскиваем всех его потомков. Потом следующий родитель и т.д.

Comment: Вот так будет еще лучше: 20 комментариев верхнего уровня + комментарии ответы на верхний уровень:

    SELECT
        t1.`id` AS  id,
        t1.`id_user` AS id_user,
        t1.`fromUser` AS fromUser,
        t1.`text` AS comment_text,
        t1.`date` AS comment_date
    FROM `comments` t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            tt2.*
        FROM 
           `comments` tt2
        WHERE 
           tt2.`parent_id` = 0
        ORDER BY tt2.`date`
        LIMIT 0 , 20
    ) t2 ON t1.`parent_id` = t2.`id` or t1.`id` = t2.`id`
    ORDER BY t1.`date`, t1.`parent_id`

Comment: ЗЫ Насколько я понимаю для mysql такой синтаксис приемлем, в других sql надо было бы использовать временную таблицу.

Comment: Я так понимаю с LIMIT всё будет нормально? Вытащатся только 20 корневых комментов и все дочерние на эти комменты. Так?

Comment: Всю голову забил уже с этими t, t1, tt2, tt2, tt1.  Ничего не получается. Не могли бы вы интегрировать эту схему в приведённый мною выше запрос. Пожалуйста.